# Server not recognizing that wget is installed on OS X Yosemite

Tags: php, httpd.conf, wget, php.ini

I'm trying to install some software (called Prohits, used for mass spectrometry data management) on a localhost server I set up. One of the requirements for the install is that I have `wget` installed. So I installed Homebrew and got `wget` and verified that it was installed by typing it in the terminal.

However, the server is giving me an error that wget is not installed. I had to use an older version of PHP for the installation so I'm wondering if that might be causing this. Does `wget` have to be linked somehow to the `php.ini` file of the older PHP version in order for the server to recognize that it is installed? I had to do something similar for it to recognize that PEAR was installed which is why I'm wondering. Or does it needed to be included in `httpd.conf`?

Comment: A quick work-around is always to simply edit the script and use the absolute path rather than just `wget`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is giving an error because Apache's `$PATH` variable does not contain `/usr/local/bin`, which is the directory that `wget` is located in. Although the system's $PATH variable contains it (so using `wget` works in the console), Apache's `$PATH` variable is separate from that.

I resolved this by adding the necessary path to the $PATH variable in Apache's `plist` file, which is in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist` in OS X. If the $PATH variable is already defined, add the path to it. If not, define it. So I added the following inside the `<dict>` tags:

```
<key>PATH</key>
<string>/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin</string>
```

I restarted my server and `wget` was recognized. You can also check that the new path is reflected in your PHP file with `echo $PATH;`.

Answer (score 1):

Check that wget is in the PATH for whichever user is running the app.

Comment: I found that it was in this path `/usr/local/Cellar/wget/1.16.3/bin/wget`, added it to .bash_profile and checked that it appeared when I put 'echo $PATH' in terminal. But when it is run by php exec on the server, I get an error stating 'sh: wget: command not found'. The user for both are the same (me).